I am using Avada theme, on wordpress goddady . Button and text inside container that is displayed in wordpress admin. for some reason it not displayed
In the link I have provided, just above footer you should see download here button. That whole container is not displayed in any device.
It works correctly on wp-admin.
I added this code block to generate that container.
Please tell what might be causing the issue?
Below are the plugins Installed
1)Akismet Anti-Spam
2)Classic Editor
3)Contact Form 7
4)Duplicate Page
5)Fusion Builder
6)Fusion Core
7)Gravity Forms
8)Health Check & Troubleshooting
9)Joinchat
10)Site Kit by Google
11)Slider Revolution
12)Unite Gallery Lite
13)UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore
14)WP Htaccess Editor
15)Yoast SEO
16)301 Redirects
Maybe I am missing a plugin or installed plugin has issue.  I cant determine the issue.
<div class="container7">
  <article>
    <h1>Procedure for installation of rooftop solar plant through National Portal</h1>
  </article>
  <div class="button-container">
    <a href="https://dynaroof.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Step-Wise-Procedure_Residential_Solar.pdf" download rel="noopener noreferrer" class="styled-button1">
      Download Here
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .container7 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row; 
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center; 
    background-color: #f89e09;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 1rem;
    height: 11rem;
  }

  .container7 article {
    flex: 2;
    padding: 1rem;
    color: white; 
    font-weight: 500;
  }

  .container7 article h1 {
    color: white; 
    font-weight: 800;
  }

  .button-container {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }

  .styled-button1 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.8rem 1rem;
    background-color: #f76500;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .styled-button1:hover {
    background-color: #de110d; 
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .container7 {
      flex-direction: column;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .button-container {
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top: 1rem;
    }
    
    .container7 article {
      padding: 0.5rem;
    }
  }
</style>

I tried to enable and disable the plugins, that I have installed. So far I didnt see any plugin causing this issue. Earlier this was made using wordpress and wasnt displaying, so I changed it to codeblock, still not working. At bottom of this page you can find its not displaying at all, https://dynaroof.com/dyna-solar/

Did you forget to put the image into the question?

You have a rather strange element in your code. It is . It should be  I can't tell which plugin and/or your own code added this. Its effect is that the HTML with the download button is interpreted as stylesheet content rather than HTML hence the button does not appear. Have a very close look at any code you have introduced.

The weird <style.> occurs just after the (or, rather, within) the 
I think therefore tht this question should be closed as the problem was created by what is basically a typo.

@AHaworth I have used  only. but i will try finding <style.> and get back to you.

@AHaworth also can you please teach me how did you find this typo? It will be very helpfull

@AHaworth it was a typo. I was using multiple code blocks to design page. Thank you for help.

I found it by going into the browser devtools inspect facility, copying all the html element (right click in mouse and selecting Edit HTML), putting it into my editor and searching for style.

@A Haworth Thank you the Help. As stated by A Haworth It was a typo, and hence my component wasnt displaying.
To find typo repeat these steps:

Open devtools in your browser
Copy all of the html elements using right click and selecting Edit HTML,
Paste the text into your editor and search for style or <style>

